# Tortoisesvn merge two branches in another one

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I have these directories as well:

- branches
- tags
- trunk

Trunk contains:

- common.txt Content is: 'trunk'
- trunkFile.txt

Also i have two branches - *A(from trunk), B(from trunk)*

Branch A modifications:

```
-common.txt:
 'trunk
  (+) A'
- add aFile.txt
```

Branch B modifications:

```
-common.txt:
 'trunk
  (+) B'
- add bFile.txt
```

All, what i need is create one more brunch (AB), whitch would be contain all changes from branch A, and from branch B. I mean:

Branch AB contains:

```
- common.txt:
  'trunk
   A
   B'
- trunkFile
- aFile
- bFile
```

What i done: I created a new branch AB from trunk. Then make merge (merge two different trees) on AB, in FROM i selected **branch A**, in TO i selected **branch B**.

The result was bad:

- strange conflict in common.txt. But it's not so bad, as the next point, because the conflict can be resolve..
- tree conflict on aFile. Tortoise said, that this file was removed (!) and at the result this file wasn't in resulting branch AB..

You may say, that i was wrong to choose Merge two diferent trees, that this tast is for Merge a range of revisions. But if it's so, how can i use Merge two different trees, except of using as reintegration a branch to trunk.
Thnks!

Comment: From my point of view reintegrate branch A and B in trunk and then make a new branch form trunk would be the cleanest way. You can't go this way?

Comment: Maybe, I'am not sure.. The task for me is to tell about tortoise tree merge (merge two different trees) on this example: We have 4 branches from trunk (A, B, C, D). How to make one brunch ABD from branches A, B, D. How to make a new branch from ABD, and then aplly to it all changes from branch C. What happens with mergeinfo during all this operations.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in 2 ways

First one
merge branch A with trunk (reintegrate a branch) and then merge branch B with trunk and then create a branch AB from Trunk

OR

Assuming that you have already created a branch AB without merging branch A and branch B to trunk. Merge branch A to branch AB using Merge two different trees option and in the From URL you should be specify branch AB URL and on To URL you should specify branch A URL and then merge branch B to branch AB using Merge two different trees option and in the From URL you should be specify branch AB URL and on To URL you should specify branch B URL

Comment: Yes, i need to do this operations, without reintegrating A and B to the trunk! Let's see the second way, you described. I have done what you said, but when i was merging B to AB, tortoise desided, that aFile(from A to AB merge) need to be deleted! And the result of B to AB merging was, that bFile exist in AB, but aFile was deleted..